# show $\int^\infty_0 e^{-sx} x^{-1} \sin{x} dx = \frac14 \log{(1+4s^{-2})}$ for $s>0$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

This is problem 2.6.58 of Folland's Real Analysis book:

show $\int^\infty_0 e^{-sx} x^{-1} \sin{x} dx = \frac14 \log{(1+4s^{-2})}$ for $s>0$ by integrating $e^{-sx} \sin{(2xy)}$ over x and y.

I get the general gist of the problem, if I integrate $e^{-sx} \sin{(2xy)}$ first with respect to $y$, and make the change of variables $z = 2xy$, I can get an integral that has an $x^{-1}$ term. I am not sure how to choose what are the boundaries I am integrating over though, or what comes next. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I take it you have looked at the answers which informed you that the statement in your question is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, evaluate $I(s)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\sin x\cdot e^{-sx}$ using the [fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) that $\sin x=\Im(e^{ix})$, then integrate both sides with regard to *s*.

Comment: You realize of course that the statement that the OP wants to prove is wrong.

Comment: @RonGordon: Perhaps somewhere along the way he confused $\arctan$ with $\text{arctanh}$. Or whatever.

Comment: No, that's not it.  It appears that somewhere, someone forgot to square the sine.

Comment: @RonGordon: Well, in their defense, the sine *is* a *circular* function, after all, and since so countless many have burned their reputation in the past by trying to square the *circle*, the person in question was naturally reticent, and feared doing something similar. :-$)$

Comment: OK, that must have been it. Totally.

Answer (score 1):

The result stated in the OP's question is not correct.  I know $s=0$ is not in the domain, but the limit as $s \to 0$ should produce an answer of $\pi/2$; the answer given by the OP blows up.

The problem lies in the fact that

$$\int_0^1 dy \, \sin{2 x y} = \frac{\sin^2{x}}{x}$$

not $\sin{x}/x$.  Thus, the integral you seek is

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-s x} \frac{\sin^2{x}}{x} = \frac14 \log{\left ( 1+\frac{4}{s^2}\right )} $$

The integral you posted is, instead

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-s x} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} = \arctan{\frac1{s}} $$

Comment: The integral of $\sin 2xy$ by $y$ is ${-1\over 2x}\cos 2xy + c$. There are no limits of integration in OP's question.

Comment: @SuzuHirose:   Even that is misleading while correct.  Better to write $$\frac{C-\cos{2 x y }}{2 x} $$  But, really, how is one supposed to get $\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ from **any** integration limits over $y$?  No wonder the OP didn't supply any integration limits - because he transcribed the problem incorrectly.  See how the answer he seeks behaves as $s \to 0$.  Sorry this means that your answer is fundamentally flawed, but there you go.

Comment: I noticed it was wrong after posting it but left it here thinking it might give someone else an idea. More haste, less speed it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Your integral is the Laplace transform of the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ where this transform is defined as 
$$\mathcal{L}(f(x))(s)=\int^{\infty}_{0}f(x)e^{-sx}\,dx$$
Laplace transform of your function $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is 
$$\mathcal{L}(\frac{\sin(x)}{x})(s)=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-sx}\,dx=\arctan(\frac{1}{s})$$ 
Therefore you should seek for another integrand to get your result.

Comment: Did you see my answer to this question, posted yesterday?

Comment: @RonGordon: yes your answer is correct.

Comment: That wasn't my point.  Rather, you are telling him to "seek another integrand," when in fact I had given it to him yesterday.

Comment: I see. Actually I provided this answer to make a connection to the Laplace transform. But you are right essentially there is nothing new in terms of result.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-sx}x^{-1}\sin\pars{x}\,\dd x
     =\arctan\pars{1 \over s}:\ {\large ?}.\quad s\ >\ 0}$.

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-sx}x^{-1}\sin\pars{x}\,\dd x}
> =\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-sx}\,\ \overbrace{%
> \half\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic k x}\,\dd k}^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{x^{-1}\sin\pars{x}}}}\,\ \dd x
> \\[5mm]&=\half\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{\pars{-s + \ic k}x}\,\dd x\,\dd k
> =\half\int_{-1}^{1}{-1 \over -s + \ic k}\,\dd k
> =\half\int_{-1}^{1}{s + \ic k \over k^{2} + s^{2}}\,\dd k
> =\int_{0}^{1}{s\,\dd k \over k^{2} + s^{2}}
> \\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{1/s}{\dd k \over k^{2} + 1}
> =\color{#66f}{\large\arctan\pars{1 \over s}}
> \end{align}